# Giving Langchain agent a JSON with many nested elements, without specifying its schema

Tags: python, json, langchain

Working in Python.

I have a `json` file that has many nested `json/dicts` within it. The nests can get very complicated so manually creating schema/functions is not an option. Each `json` differs drastically.

Below is an example of a `json`. A lot of the data is not necessary, and this holds true for other jsons from the same source.

**Question is**, how do I get a `langchain` agent to use the entire `json` as context, then answer questions from it?

I would like it to work for a `json` that I have never seen before.,

```
{'parent': {'type': 'database_id',
   'database_id': 'fcb025d8-914d-46c8-9898-028b76907bdb'},
  'archived': False,
  'properties': {'Contacted Employee': {'id': '%3DsOA',
    'type': 'checkbox',
    'checkbox': False},
   'Job Description': {'id': 'B%3D%5Eq',
    'type': 'url',
    'url': 'URL_TO_JOB_POST'},
   'How': {'id': 'LZOz',
    'type': 'multi_select',
    'multi_select': [{'id': 'bc945f90-c4c1-4e5c-8df9-0a08dda55481',
      'name': 'LinkedIn Application',
      'color': 'yellow'}]},
   'Last Contacted': {'id': 'L%7D%60p',
    'type': 'date',
    'date': {'start': '2024-02-22', 'end': None, 'time_zone': None}},
   'Status': {'id': 'W%5C%7B%7C',
    'type': 'status',
    'status': {'id': '}K]}', 'name': 'Rejected', 'color': 'red'}},
   'Company': {'id': 'bsDB',
    'type': 'rich_text',
    'rich_text': [{'type': 'text',
      'text': {'content': 'The Company Name', 'link': None},
      'annotations': {'bold': False,,
      'plain_text': 'The Company Name',
      'href': None}]},
   'Date applied': {'id': 'yR%5BZ',
    'type': 'date',
    'date': {'start': '2024-02-22', 'end': None, 'time_zone': None}},
   'Name': {'id': 'title',
    'type': 'title',
    'title': [{'type': 'text',
      'text': {'content': 'Growth Marketing', 'link': None},
      'annotations': {'bold': False,
       'italic': False,
       'strikethrough': False,
       'underline': False,
       'code': False,
       'color': 'default'},
      'plain_text': 'Growth Marketing',
      'href': None}]}},}
```

I tried running custom fucntions for this one `json`, but that does not scale for unseen jsons. Below is what I used.

**note:** I also tried `Pydantic` output parser but that also requires manual configurations.

```
def generate_summary_for_all_applications(data):
"""Generate a comprehensive summary of all job applications."""
summary = ""
for app in data:
    summary += f"Job Title: {app['job_title']}, Company: {app['company']}, Status: {app['status']}\n"
return summary

def ask_llm_about_all_applications(question, all_data_summary):
"""Ask the LLM a question based on a summary of all applications."""
response = llm.generate(f"{all_data_summary}\n{question}")
return response

all_data_summary = generate_summary_for_all_applications(processed_data)

response = ask_llm_about_all_applications("What are the next steps for the applications?", all_data_summary)

print(response)
```